# Tan(z/2) about pi/2 power series expansion without Bernouilli numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry

For a basic complex variables class (not too rigorous or deep) I am asked for homework to find th expansion of tan(z/2) about $\pi /2 $  I looked online but all I could find was expressions using the bernouilli numbers but a) they were never seen in class and b) the fact it gives the $a_n$ to be the evaluation of the derivatives at $\pi/4$ suggests some neat trick I think. Haven't been able to find it. The first found by chugging in mathematica were 1 2 4 16 80 512. 
If somebody could give me a clue would be much appreciated. Just something to kick it off at least.
Please, don't mark as duplicate for the other answer which has some Bn s in the expression.

Comment: Is that sequence the derivatives evaluated at $\pi/2$?

Comment: yes, but the derivatives of tan(z/2)

Comment: Did you use the chain rule? $\tan(\pi/4)=1$, $\frac{1}{2}\sec^2(\pi/4)=1$, and I think the third one is also $1$ as well. Check with [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expand+tan(z%2F2)+at+pi%2F2)?

Comment: I checked with mathematica, the sequence is in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a truncated series, may be you could start using $z=2t+\frac \pi 2$ which makes $$\tan(\frac z2)=\tan(t+\frac \pi 4)=\frac{\sin(t+\frac \pi 4) }{\cos(t+\frac \pi 4) }=\frac{\cos (t)+\sin (t)}{\cos (t)-\sin (t)}$$ and use, around $t=0$, the standard Taylor expansions .

Since $$\sin(t)=t-\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^5}{120}-\frac{t^7}{5040}+O\left(t^{9}\right)$$ $$\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24}-\frac{t^6}{720}+\frac{t^8}{40320}+O\left(t^{9}\right)$$ this would give $$\frac{\cos (t)+\sin (t)}{\cos (t)-\sin (t)}=\frac{1+t-\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^4}{24}+\frac{t^5}{120}-\frac{t^6}{720}-\frac{t^7}{5040}+\frac{t^8}{40320}+O\left(t^9\right) }{1-t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^4}{24}-\frac{t^5}{120}-\frac{t^6}{720}+\frac{t^7}{5040}+\frac{t^8}{40320}+O\left(t^9\right) }$$ Now, long division to get $$\frac{\cos (t)+\sin (t)}{\cos (t)-\sin (t)}=1+2 t+2 t^2+\frac{8 t^3}{3}+\frac{10 t^4}{3}+\frac{64 t^5}{15}+\frac{244
   t^6}{45}+\frac{2176 t^7}{315}+\frac{554 t^8}{63}+O\left(t^9\right)$$ Now, go back to $t=\frac 12(z-\frac \pi 2)$.

Comment: I was looking at a nice close form, but maybe there isn't one and he just wanted us to specify the first few terms..which would be quite not cool if you ask me. Thanks though. Why did you split sin/cos into cos + sin over cos - sin may I ask?